# Python: File Writing Adding Unintentional Newlines on Linux Only

Tags: python, linux, io, newline

I am using Python 2.7.9. I'm working on a program that is supposed to produce the following output in a .csv file per loop:

```
URL,number
```

Here's the main loop of the code I'm using:

```
csvlist = open(listfile,'w')

f = open(list, "r")
def hasQuality(item):
    for quality in qualities:
        if quality in item:
            return True
    return False

for line in f:
    line = line.split('\n')
    line = line[0]
    # print line
    itemname = urllib.unquote(line).decode('utf8')
    # print itemhash

    if hasQuality(itemname):
        try:
        looptime = time.time()
        url = baseUrl + line
            results = json.loads(urlopen(url).read())
            # status = results.status_code
            content = results
            if 'median_price' in content:
                medianstr = str(content['median_price']).replace('$','')
            medianstr = medianstr.replace('.','')
                median = float(medianstr)
                volume = content['volume']
                print url+'\n'+itemname
                print 'Median: $'+medianstr
                print 'Volume: '+str(volume)
                if (median > minprice) and (volume > minvol):
                    csvlist.write(line + ',' + medianstr + '\n')
                    print '+ADDED TO LIST'
            else:
                print 'No median price given for '+itemname+'.\nGiving up on item.'
        print "Finished loop in " + str(round(time.time() - looptime,3)) + " seconds."
    except ValueError:
        print "we blacklisted fool?? cause we skippin beats"
    else:
        print itemname+'is a commodity.\nGiving up on item.'

csvlist.close()
f.close()

print "Finished script in " + str(round(time.time() - runtime, 3)) + " seconds."
```

It **should** be generating a list that looks like this:

```
AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29,3911 
M4A1-S%20%7C%20Hyper%20Beast%20%28Field-Tested%29,4202
```

But it's *actually* generating a list that looks like this:

```
AWP%20%7C%20Asiimov%20%28Field-Tested%29
,3911
M4A1-S%20%7C%20Hyper%20Beast%20%28Field-Tested%29
,4202
```

Whenever it is ran on a Windows machine, I have no issue. Whenever I run it on my EC2 instance, however, it adds that extra newline. Any ideas why? Running commands on the file like

```
awk 'NR%2{printf $0" ";next;}1' output.csv
```

do not do anything. I have transferred it to my Windows machine and it still reads the same. However, when I paste the output into Steam's chat client it concatenates it in the way that I want.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Blind guess: check if your input file uses CRLF as line terminator, I'm not sure if `\n` would obey the OS-specific convention and you'd see half of your terminators making it into the output on Linux.

Comment: Hi!  Unfortunately you don't get to remove your question text; that makes the answer useless, and self-vandalism isn't allowed.  If you really want, you can contact the moderators and ask for the question to be dissociated from your account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where the problem occurs

**code:**

```
csvlist.write(line + ',' + medianstr + '\n')
```

This can be cleared is you strip the space

**modified code:**

```
csvlist.write(line.strip() + ',' + medianstr + '\n')
```

**Problem:**

The problem is due to the fact `you are reading raw lines from the input file`

Raw_lines contain `\n` to indicate there is a new line for every line which is not the last and for the last line it just ends with the given character .

*for more details:*

`Just type print(repr(line)) before writing and see the output`

Comment: EDIT: I just saw your updated post. I'll try this and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: This did solve it, @Vignesh. Thank you very much! I was going mad attempting to figure out what was wrong. :)